# How to store the inserted images in flutter even after uninstalling the app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm developing an app in flutter which deals with images. after inserting images through my app the images are added to the database(where I use SQLite for storage).but when I uninstall my app, the whole data is lost. the original images are deleted which causes a major problem. I couldn't find a solution for this.

I'm using image_picker plugin to add images to my app. I have no idea about the storage

Comment: Anything stored locally is going to get deleted when uninstalling, if you need to persist stuff that survives uninstalls you will need to back your images up to a cloud service or something

Comment: What is the reason for keeping app related images if the app no longer exists?